# Automatic Section Title & Section Title Before Section Number

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to do 3 things:

1. Repeat a section title automatically for each section (e.g., "Chapter").
2. Place the section title before the section number (e.g., "Chapter 1" and NOT "1 Chapter").
3. Make each section number 2 digits long (e.g., "Chapter 01" and NOT "Chapter 1").

I've been able to find how to do each of these 3 things individually but not altogether.

Comment: Which document class are you using? When you say "section", what exactly do you mean; i.e., a sectional unit created through `\chapter`, `\section`?

Comment: "Chapter" was probably a bad example. My LaTeX file is actually an "article" listing equations, and I want each section to be labelled "Equation 01", "Equation 02", etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. The standard `book` and `report` document classes give you `\chapter` which does what you need by default.
2. The standard `book` and `report` document classes give you `\chapter` which does what you need by default.
3. You can use the kernel's `\two@digits`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thechapter{\two@digits{\value{chapter}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case what you are trying to achieve is a running title, use `titlesec` to change the formatting from `display` to `block`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thechapter{\two@digits{\value{chapter}}}
\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {1em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]